# Splitting Xpath in PHP

Tags: php, xpath

HTML that will be parsed:

```
<tr>
 <td>18</td>
 <td>1:0 <img src="./img/goal.gif"></td>
 <td>18</td>
 <td>Player1</td>
 <td>Team1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>34</td>
 <td><img src="./img/sub.gif"></td>
 <td>13 <img src="./img/in.gif"><br>11 <img src="./img/out.gif"></td>
 <td>Player1<br>Player2</td>
 <td>Team2</td>
</tr>
```

td[3] and td[4] have two values sometimes and when there are two (divided by br), I need to split them so that that the row (in this case tr[2]) would be displayed twice, once with both Player1 and Player2 like that:

```
tr[1] 18, goal, 18, Player1, Team1
tr[2] 34, in, 13, Player1, Team2
tr[2] 34, out, 11, Player2, Team2
```

So basically everything that is before the break is part of one entry, and everything after the break in the other. When there is only one value, both rows must have it.

Comment: I think this would be easier if a different formatting was used. Why not nest tables when the double condition happens instead of using a <br/> tag? If you are going to use HTML I would recommend taking advantage of the structural features it employs a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible in XPath 1, but in XPath 2 you can use:

```
/tr/(if (.//br) then 
(td[1], "in",  td[3]/text()[1], td[4]/text()[1], td[5],
 td[1], "out", td[3]/text()[2], td[4]/text()[2], td[5])
else (td[1], "goal", td[3], td[4], td[5])
)
```

using //br to detect which case it is, and the returning the corresponding tuple(s).

Since sequences can't be nested, the result value of this query is a single sequence like this (with type annotations)

```
sequence: (
  node: 18, string: goal, node: 18, node: Player1, node: Team1, 
  node: 34, string: in, node: 13, node: Player1, node: Team2, 
  node: 34, string: out, node: 11, node: Player2, node: Team2)
```

which you can easily split at every 5th element

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that <br/> would work. However, please note that you're using <br> (missing a forward slash). Does that change your code?

Also, why not use some code to induce "rowspan" or "colspan" for certain rows?